# Incrementing a Counter Index in MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

So i'm working on a web app using the Spotify api and i store track Id's in a field(they are unique), in the database that the user adds to their account's playlist, and if different users add the same tracks I want a field of that specific track's document to increment a counter if the same unique track id field is about to be added, basically representing how many times that one track was added to a user's playlist. Is this possible and considered within good practice? If not, what are alternatives

```
            const playlist1 = {
            track: tracks[currentTrack].name,
            trackID:tracks[currentTrack].id,
            year:parseInt(this.state.year),
            genre:this.state.genre,
            album: tracks[currentTrack].album.name,
            artist: tracks[currentTrack].artists[0].name,
            artistID: tracks[currentTrack].artists[0].id,
            count: 1,
        }
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/track/add', playlist1)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data));
```

This is how I initialize a document into the database with a count of 1, but obviously I'd need to make some sort of conditional statement to find if the 'trackID' field already exists, and if so increment the 'counter' field

Comment: Use $push while updating.

Comment: isnt that for arrays

Comment: Right, $inc is for counters.

Comment: did you see the code i posted, and so $inc is what I should use and not $push?

Comment: The word "index" already means a specific thing in MongoDB, I suggest you reword your question to use different terms for avoidance of confusion.

Comment: isn't index like a parameter for a document, sorry im new to mongodb and backend development in general

Comment: No, that's not what it is.

Comment: lol ok got it fixed though